# Modifying GridView to work with only One group and multiple items within that group

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am trying to customize gridview prebuilt template.  By Default it has multiple groups and multiple items within each group.

I only have a single group and multiple items for that group. How can i configure gridview to work with my needs.

Can anyone please let me know of any online resource or any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried ANYTHING ? If yes, please post some code.

Comment: It is polite to mark the correct/best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one group, then really you don't have any groups. My suggestion for you is to use a `GridView` and do not use grouping. So, don't tell the `CollectionViewSource` to group your data, since really you are not grouping - you might even just bind to your list directly.

Then the "Group Heading" can be placed in the `Header` property of the `GridView` or just above it in the UI if you want. Again, you do NOT have to group in a `GridView` and it sounds like you don't want to anyway. This does NOT mean you lose any functionality.

Best of luck!